# struts2 package extends json

Tags: json, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I have a package which contains many actions and it extends tiles-default package.
Now I have a requirement that, These actions should return json result instead of tiles.

Can I use the same actions & package to return both types of result?
Is there any way, the package extends both "json-default" and "tiles-default"?

```
<package name="deposit" namespace="/deposit" extends="tiles-default">
```

Please suggest.

Comment: You need to determine how the client will access the tiles and json results, you need some way to differentiate. Easiest is to create a new package which extends deposit AND json-default and set the default result type to json.

Answer (score 2):

Sure why not. Use `,` to separate packages.

```
<package name="deposit" namespace="/deposit" extends="tiles-default,json-default">
```